# UK Online Stock Tradiing for Beginner and Small Amounts?

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom

I'm interested in experimenting with buying and selling stocks and shares online. I would like to start following share performance and studying financial markets in stocks. I've been reading the financial times guide to the markets and I would like to get started. What is the best service for a UK baseed beginner who wants to start small.

Comment: Suggestion: http://money.stackexchange.com/a/41882/11768

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this: http://www.halifax.co.uk/sharedealing/our-accounts/fantasy-trader/

Virtual or fantasy trading is a great way to immerse yourself in that world and not lose your money whilst you make basic mistakes.

Once real money is involved, there are some online platforms that are cheaper for lower amount investing than others. This article is a good, recent starting point for you:  http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/diyinvesting/article-1718291/Pick-best-cheapest-investment-Isa-platform.html

Best of luck in the investment casino!

*(And only risk money you can afford to lose - as with any form of investment, gambling, etc)*

Comment: is referring to investing in such loaded terms helpful here

Comment: It's my view of stock-picking. Choosing shares is very much riskier than buying the market. The subset of investment that is stock-picking shouldn't be classed as the same risk as - say - buying an index tracker. I was intending to point that out. And I had also assumed that the desire to stock-pick comes from the belief that the OP could 'beat the market'. Odds are stacked against that happening unfortunately.